# WHERE clause not getting attched in SQL SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

i am trying to run simple query as below which filter out result on status. if Active, Inactive or ALL.

```
  IF (@Status = ''
    OR @Status IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'ALL'
  END

  DECLARE @strParam AS varchar(max)

  SET @strParam =  'Status: ' +
  REPLACE(@Status, '''', '')

  SET @strSql = 'SELECT [UserName],[FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[IsActive],''' + @strParam + '''  As Param
    ,''' + @strLink
  + ''' AS CompanyLogo
FROM [gblUserMaster] '

  print @strsql
  print @Status
  IF @Status = 'Active'
  BEGIN
    SET @strSql = @strSql + ' WHERE IsActive = 1'
      print @strsql
  END
  IF @Status = 'Inactive'
  BEGIN
    SET @strSql = @strSql + ' WHERE IsActive = 0'
      print @strsql
  END

  SET @strSql = @strSql + ' ORDER BY gblUserMaster.UserName'
  print @strsql
  EXEC (@strSql)
```

@Status = Active i am getting result but WHERE clause not getting attched.... 
Print giving me below query

```
SELECT [UserName],[FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[IsActive],'Status: Active'  As Param
    ,'' AS CompanyLogo
FROM [gblUserMaster]  ORDER BY gblUserMaster.UserName
```

BUT there is no WHERE clause
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us where you are setting the parameters prior to running this?

Comment: What is the size of `@strsql` variable? Also, show the print statements that you are getting and can you print the `@Status` just before executing?

Comment: Status AS varchar(max) = NULL  its input parameter....i am getting result also  print Status  giving me Active , which is correcet  only thing Where clause not getting attched to query... ORDER BY  getting attched

Comment: `varchar(max)` for some reason won't work. Set to `varchar(4000)` instead.

Comment: nope nothing happens setting 4000

Comment: SELECT [UserName],[FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[IsActive],'Status: Active' As Param ,'' AS CompanyLogo FROM [gblUserMaster] ORDER BY gblUserMaster.UserName     i am getting ORDER BY attched not WHERE  clause where Status is 'Active'

Comment: I can't say what the problem is, but I would add the following code, 'ELSE  SET strSql = strSql + ' WHERE IsActive = 2'
      print strsql

(Add at symbols for variables of course)  Perhaps @status isn't really what you think it is.

Comment: What do you see if you `print '"' + @Status + '"'`? Does it come back with spaces, etc., before it, e.g.: `"      Active"`?